# How to use wm_deadchar to send non Ascii signs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i'm trying to send an umlaut keyevent with the function keybd_event. The Windows Documentation states that: "A dead key is a key that generates a character, such as the umlaut (double-dot), that is combined with another character to form a composite character. For example, the umlaut-O character (Ö) is generated by typing the dead key for the umlaut character, and then typing the O key."

How do i emit a dead key?

I tried the following without success:

```
keybd_event(WM_DEADCHAR,0x0103,0,0);
keybd_event(0x4F,0,0,0);
```

Sorry for my bad english.
I look forward to your reply.

Comment: Have you tried the usual `SendInput()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `keybd_event` is a virtual-key code. E.g. for my keyboard the dead key `"` is `VK_OEM_7`.